PDF file too big for convertion to Excel
I would like to batch convert PDF files to Excel with this code:
 Sub JobPackconverter()
 Dim PDFFol As String, PDFout As String, Targetdir As String
 Dim pdf_path As String, excel_path As String

 PDFFol = GetFolder
 PDFout = "Converted"
 Targetdir = PDFFol & Application.PathSeparator & PDFout


 If Not FolderExists(Targetdir) Then
 MkDir Targetdir
 End If

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value = PDFFol
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").Value = PDFFol & "\" & PDFout

 pdf_path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")
 excel_path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3")


 Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
 Dim fo As Folder
 Dim f As file

 Set fo = fso.GetFolder(pdf_path)

 Dim wa As Object
 Dim doc As Object
 Dim wr As Object

 Set wa = CreateObject("word.application")

 wa.Visible = True

 Dim nwb As Workbook
 Dim nsh As Workbook

 For Each f In fo.Files
 Set doc = wa.Documents.Open(f.path, False, Format:="PDF Files")
 Set wr = doc.Paragraphs(1).Range
 wr.WholeStory

 Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
 Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)
 wr.Copy

 nsh.Paste
 nwb.SaveAs (excel_path & Replace(f.Name, ".pdf", ".xlsx"))

 doc.Close False
 nwb.Close False

 Next
 wa.Quit

 End Sub

Unfortunately the error below doesn't allow me to do this.
Is there some way to have it working?


The PDF file has exactly 19 pages and counts around 8MB

@KJ You're right, I misread the screencap

Honestly I need just first 3 pages. Is there any way of how could I do it by VBA? (Or other question is required)

Easiest way would be to create a PDF with only the first three pages and convert those

The PDF is generated automatically as a whole, can VBA Excel extract these first 3 pages only?
